# IOptionsSnapshot get all registered names

Tags: c#, .net

Using `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot` you can configure one config class multiple times.

Imagine I have:

```
{
    "MyObject": {
        "AnotherObject": {
            "Address": { "City": "..." } // Will be named as "MyObject:AnotherObject:Address" in the snapshot
        }
    },
    "AnotherSetting": {
        "Address": { "City": "..." } 
            // This object will be registered with a Guid.ToString() 
            // (I cannot change the package registering it)
    }
    "FavoriteAddresses" {
        "Home": { "City": "..." },
        "Work": { "City": "..." },
        "Parents": { "City": "..." },
        // ...... Unlimited list
    }
}
```

I have to deal with the following restrictions:

- I cannot change my `Address` class to add a `Name` property and transform `FavoriteAddresses` to an array
- Neither I can apply inheritance or have wrapper around this `Address` class

As you can see, many Address objects and for some it is impossible to know the chosen name.
Regardless where it is registered, it all ends up as a **named option**.

**So how can I get a list of all registred names for the `Address` options?**